# Wrap a c library in a swift framework for iOS development

Tags: ios, swift, module-map

I have crosscompiled c library for iOS on Linux with clang.
Now I want to create a re-usable framework for Swift proejects. What I have is the dylib and the C-Header.
But I'm not sure how to start from here. Most tutorials that I found were pretty outdated. I read about bridging headers and module maps already. THe latter seem the way to go nowadays.
If anyone could point me in the right direction from there I'd appreciate it.